# Null check and comparing in then clause

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in my database. First one is called F and the second one is T. F stores two information. "date_received" and "date_removed" that can be null. T stores only "date" that is an arbitrary date.
F can store information for an object. For instance,

2019-05-19        2019-05-31 ==> Means it belonged to someone between these dates

2019-06-03        NULL ==> Means it still belongs to someone.

I have two dates in T , 2019-05-25 and 2019-06-05.
It is easy to find for 2019-05-25 because I can use BETWEEN clause but
2019-06-05 I cannot. 
I need to write if-else or case condition to check that if F.date_removed is null or not

```
CASE
  WHEN F.date_removed IS NULL THEN T.date > F.date_received
  ELSE  T.date BETWEEN F.date_received AND F.date_removed
END
```

How can I handle this issue. I need to switch between two comparing options according to being null of "date_removed"

Comment: `CASE` is used to produce values, not to compare fields. What you wrote doesn't return anything and won't even compile. T-SQL doesn't have a `bool` type (bit isn't a logical type) and logical expressions don't produce results the way they do in other languages.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Filter rows or produce `1/0` results based on some conditions? In the first case, you use put the expressions in the WHERE clause. IN the second case you should rewrite the cases to return explicit values, eg `CASE WHEN F.date_removed IS NULL AND T.date > F.date_received THEN 1 WHEN T.date BETWEEN F.date_received AND F.date_removed THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis, my goal was simpler than so the recommendation of Eliseu Marcos solved the issue

Comment: which means you didn't need a `CASE` in the first place

Comment: @DDemirci, instead of changing the question title to "SOLVED", just mark the appropriate answer. That will help other users find the solution and reward those that help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand this your rule will stay in the where clause, so you can do this way.

```
WHERE
((F.date_removed IS NULL AND T.date > F.date_received) OR (T.date BETWEEN F.date_received AND F.date_removed))
```

Comment: Thank you Eliseu, that is what I am trying to do

Comment: If this solved the problem @DDemirci you should mark this as the solution, rather than editing your title to have "-- solved".

Comment: I'd recommend changing `T.date > F.date_received` to `T.date >= F.date_received`, since you're using `BETWEEN`, which is inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, which is slightly less wordy.

```
WHERE
        T.date >= F.date_received
    AND (F.date_removed IS NULL OR T.date <= F.date_removed)
```